# Split a string and compare with an array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

So i have the following string and array string

Example 1

```
string str = "name1, something2,else , any,thing";
string[] strArray = {"name1" , "something2,else"  , "any,thing"};
```

Example 2

```
   string str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G"
   string [] strArray = {"A,B" , "C", "D,E", "F,G","I,J,K","L,M","H,N"}

string[] outputArray = {"A,B" , "C", "D,E", "F,G"}
```

so how do i compare str with strArray to split it properly?

Please note that strArray is not the output but it is an input array to help with understanding the split for the string str.

Comment: @DStanley Because it would capture the comma between 2 and 2 in "name2,2"

Comment: Your split logic makes no sense. there is no pattern. It's random groupings.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead You are right, it looks totally arbitrary.

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close.

Comment: can't we somehow compare str and strArray to get the outputArray?

Comment: @blank It would help if you could tell us about your split logic, as it would be helpful in comparing the array and string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the generic Split which will split on a space, then you can use [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9.aspx) to remove the unwanted commas, something like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char[] trimchar = {','};
    string str = "name1, name2,2 ,name3";
    var result = str.Split();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = result[i].Trim(trimchar);
    }


    string[] strArray = { "name1", "name2,2", "name3" };
}
```

Or as Simon suggested you could Split on a combination of comma and space something like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] trimChars = { " ,", ", " }; //Note leading and trailing commas
    string str = "name1, name2,2 ,name3,new";
    string[] strArray = { "name1", "name2,2", "name3" };
}
```

Edit base on OP's last comment about using the strArray to check for valid items. Using String.Compare and putting the results into a `List<String>` it is easier doing it that way instead of redimming an Array because of not knowing the number of items.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string str = "A,B,C,D,E,F,G";
    string[] strArray = { "A,B", "C", "D,E", "F,G", "I,J,K", "L,M", "H,N" };

    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in strArray)
    {
        if (str.Contains(item))
        {
            results.Add(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There is probably a more efficient way (like, perhaps, splitting on a comma and a space in a single call).. but the OP doesn't appear to have defined the requirements well enough.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I know, there is probably a lot cleaner way.

Comment: i cannot even split by space because the string might be as follows ...string str="A,B,2,C" and string[] strArray = {"A" , "B,2" , "C"}

Comment: i have edited the question to make it more clear..

Comment: @blank you are showing us a problem that has no rules, it looks like it is random and can be in any format, in order to separate it you will have to have something that tells you what is expected.

Comment: the expectation comes from the array strArray which may have more strings than in str....the solution would somehow compare str and strArray and get the ouputArray

Answer (score 0):

You can split via Regex:

```
string[] strArray = Regex.Split(str, @",(?!\d)");

// Captures "name1", "name2,2" and "name3"
```

Meaning:

> Capture commas, where the next character is not a number.

Comment: the next character is not necessarily a number ..it can be anything...i will edit the question to be more specific

Comment: What is your criteria then? Capture "name" followed by anything that isn't also "name"? What about splitting via a comma followed by a space?